# Algorithm that matches people based on multiple possible matches

Tags: algorithm, match

Let's say I have a set of 5 people `P = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and I know that there are the following possibilities of matching them together:

```
{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,5}, {2,1}, {2,4}, {2,5}, {3,1}, {3,4}, {4,2}, {4,3}, {4,5}, {5,1}, {5,2}, {5,4}
```

> For example they could symbolise who likes who (everyone is bisexual,
>   gender doesn't matter).

Visualised as a graph:
[image]

Now I want to actually know who to match with each other so that everybody is matched with someone. Ideally no one is left out.

> So based on the example: Who should get married with whom? Ideally no one should stay single.

**A little twist:** Also up to 3 people could be matched together.

> So based on the example: polyamorous marriage is allowed.

So I can do it manually and get a result that works. So I know that because of `{1,2}`, `{1,5}` and `{2,5}` I can match `{1,2,5}` together.

Now that means that persons 1,2 and 5 are out, which only leaves the following combinations:

```
{3,4}, {4,3}
```

Which leads to `{3,4}`.

**So the final result could be: {1,2,5} and {3,4}**

> So based on the example: Person 1, 2 and 5 get married and person 3
>   and 5 get married.

Again, visualised as a graph:
[image]

Now, this is a toy example. It get's much more complicated if the number of people and possible matches goes up.

I am looking for a push in the right direction on how to solve such a problem with a computer.

Comment: This is maximum 3-hypergraph matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching (NP-hard). Possibly a maximum bipartite matching can be used as a reasonable starting point for heuristics.

Comment: (or maybe just graph coloring, also NP-hard)

Comment: Thanks @NiklasB.! That already helps a lot.

Comment: I added a visual explanation to my question. 

@NiklasB.: If I understand it correctly bipartie matching is not possible because I don't have two parties that I try to match but one party where everyone could be a match with another one?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Thanks, I will give it a look.

Comment: @elevendollar Bipartite matching will give you groups of size 2. Hence my suggestion to use that as an initial solution and iterate on it. It's by no means a full solution idea

Comment: There are polynomial time maximum matching algorithms even for non-bipartite graphs. However, this problem does seems like it is probably NP-hard. Do you have specific sizes for your graph in mind? There might be good heuristic algorithms that work if the graph is not too large, or you can tolerate some error.

Comment: Can please confirm the following: Your problem is to connect each person with at least one another person? so your original problem does not require a connect graph and does not require match of 3 persons right? you can live with 2 person for each match if the number of ppl is even. right? because demonstrating the 3 match persons is really confusing to discribe the problem!! also do you need the solution with the minimum complexity or with minimum connections?

Comment: @hasan83 Yes, ideally I want to connect each person with at least one other person with the extra twist that also a connection of 3 people is allowed. That has to be based on the information I already have about potential matches (see first graph). Not sure about the last question.

Comment: I added a real-life example to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @arghbleargh Roughly 50.000 - 100.000

Comment: @elevendollar Sorry I misunderstood your initial comment. The graph is not bipartite, but you can still compute a maximum matching in polynomial time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Comment: Thanks @NiklasB. Will have a good look.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a somewhat brutal recursive Python function like

```
# people is a frozenset
# conflicts is a set of frozenset pairs
def match(people, conflicts):
    if not people:  # people is empty
        return {}
    for group in next_groups(people, conflicts):
        solution = match(people - group, conflicts)
        if solution is not None:
            solution.add(group)
            return solution
    return None


def next_groups(people, conflicts):
    a = min(people)
    for b in people - {a}:
        if frozenset({a, b}) in conflicts:
            continue
        yield frozenset({a, b})
        for c in people - {a, b}:
            if frozenset({a, c}) in conflicts or frozenset({b, c}) in conflicts:
                continue
            yield frozenset({a, b, c})
```

and memoize it (look up `people` in a dictionary to see what the output was last time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have a proper look to it.

Comment: I am not sure what `conflicts` is. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @elevendollar Pair of nodes with no edge between them.

Comment: Thanks! In that case that makes sense. It's also just a greedy algorithm and I was hoping for a more optimised solution but it answers my question so it gets an upvote from me.

Comment: @elevendollar It's not greedy -- it backtracks.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the backtracking? My Python knowledge is not the best.